# How to log PHP errors in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker container

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP Docker container that I am deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am relatively new to Docker and EB, so still learning. I am trying to log php errors to /var/log/php_error.log preferably.

In php.ini I have set

```
log_errors = On
error_log =  /var/log/php_error.log
```

Then I load a page with `error_log("Hi")` inside it, but when I `eb ssh` into the server, the php_error.log file was not created.

I think its a permission issue. The PHP user (www-data) doesn't have permission to write to the log directory which is owned by root. I never set a root password and can't find any documentation of how to get sudo powers or how to set the permissions properly to get this to work. I suspect its something that I can put in my Dockerfile, but I am still new to Docker so don't know exactly what to do.

Probably for the same or similar reasons I cannot write to any file with PHP, for example doing `file_put_contents("write.txt","hi")` gives a permissions error.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this and here is what I did.

Using .ebextensions you can change nearly any configuration you wish including things in php.ini.  In your EB deployment zip file make sure you have a folder named .ebextensions along with .config which contains something like the example below.

Here is an example of my PHP-specific extension:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/uploads.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 128M
      post_max_size = 128M
      error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log
```

Similar to you I put a random error_log() statement in where I knew it would be hit and the file was both created and populated with what I expected.

Hope this helps!